# How to execute a v-html attached to a function only once?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a Vue component which has Tabs ( bootstrap-vue ). Inside each tab there are radio buttons. The label of each radio is being populated using v-html property. The problem here is each time I switch between the tabs the method appendPresetHtml() is called and html overlaps here, I want to call the method only once for each radio ( other case if content is already present inside no need to again call the method to overlap and populate ). No need to call them each time I'm switching between tabs In the appendPresetHtml method I'n generating dynamic html that is appended to that particular div. I'm not getting thsi to work properly.

```
<b-tabs id="presets-tab" pills class="consent-type-tab" v-model="tabIndex">
    <b-tab v-for="bannerDesign in availableBannerDesigns" :key="bannerDesign">
        <b-form-radio-group name="preset-list" v-model="selectedPreset.id">
            <template v-for="(preset, index) in templatePresets">
                <b-form-radio :value="preset.id" :key="preset.name" v-if="filteredPresets(preset, bannerDesign)" :disabled="isRecommendedPresetDisabled(preset)" @change="selectPreset(preset, index)"> <!--  -->
                    <div v-html="appendPresetHtml(preset)" :id="'preset-box-'+ preset.id" :class="[ 'preset-'+ preset.settings.theme, isRecommendedPresetDisabled(preset) ? 'radio-opacity preset-'+ preset.settings.consentBarType : 'preset-'+ preset.settings.consentBarType,]"></div>     
                </b-form-radio>
            </template>
        </b-form-radio-group>
    </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

As i know `v-if` removes element from DOM so it should rerender element each time it becomes `true`.
I think you can try to use `v-show` because this directive will just change `display` attribute.
Information about: [v-if](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if) and [v-show](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-show)

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The problem is with the logic of using v-html="appendPresetHtml(preset)" I guess. Did you mean to change this line of code - v-if="filteredPresets(preset, bannerDesign)" ? that didn't help either

Comment: @theFrontEndDev `appendPresetHtml(preset)` using item from v-for cycle, so it should be left, bue v-if removes element from DOM each time you change tab, v-show will just hide it. anyway this fix should be implemented, because your DOM disappears each toggle.

Comment: @theFrontEndDev just thought, you can call appendPresetHtml only once in `mounted`
hook and save result to array and then just pass it to v-html, like: `v-html="preset.html"`